# Javascript: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined, typeerror, addeventlistener

I got an error in my javascript code. It is to open a Hamburger Menu in my webpage. ErrorMessage:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
at script.js:4

```
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle-button")[0]
const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-links")[0]

toggleButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  navbarLinks.classList.toggle("active")
})
```

what is wrong?

Comment: Your classname queries didn't return any elements. **When** does this script run? Is it in the `<head>` of your document or somewhere else?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("toggle-button")[0]` is undefined. Are you sure there's an element with the class `toggle-button` in the DOM at the time that you run this script?

Comment: FYI, `const toggleButton = querySelector('.toggle-button')` is shorter

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

That means that `toggleButton` is `undefined`, so the most likely problem is that at the time `document.getElementsByClassName("toggle-button")` ran, there was no matching element.

Comment: See the linked duplicate question; if you're running your JavaScript in a block of code before that HTML, then the elements won't be found since they're not yet in the page.

Comment: ahh ok, thank you so much!